# h:dataTable binding => duplicate ID

Tags: java, jsf

I have a problem using HtmlDataTable for viewing data from database.

When I create  component, the table has sometimes (not always) **twice number of columns**.

It is shown correctly and after several refreshes (without move in dtb or something) there is for example 6 columns instead of 3 and application (sometimes) become unstable.
Since this time I can't work with table because it reports "duplicate Id for a component"..

Simple example (source: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html):

```
<h:form id="bde">  
    <h:dataTable id="tbl"  
                 binding="#{myBDE.dataTable}"  
                 value="#{myBDE.dataList}"   
                 var="bdeItem">  
    <h:column>  
      <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="S" />  
      </f:facet>  
      <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.s}" rendered="#{!myBDE.editModeRow}"/>  
      <h:inputText value="#{bdeItem.s}" rendered="#{myBDE.editModeRow}" required="true" size="3"/>  
    </h:column>  

    <h:column>  
      <f:facet name="header">  
         <h:outputText value="ID" />  
      </f:facet>  
      <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.id}"/>  
    </h:column>  
  </h:dataTable>  
</h:form>
```

And java.class

```
protected HtmlDataTable dataTable;  

public void setDataTable(HtmlDataTable dataTable)   
{  
  this.dataTable = dataTable;  
}  

public HtmlDataTable getDataTable()   
{  
  if (dataTable == null)   
  {  
     dataTable = new HtmlDataTable();  
     dataTable.setRows(DEFAULT_TABLE_ROWS);  
   }  
   return dataTable;  
}
```

And the Error message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Component ID j_idt92:bde:tbl:j_idt129 has already been found in the view.    
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:422)  

root cause  

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID j_idt92:bde2:tbl:j_idt129 has already been found in the view.    
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:821)  
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)  
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)  
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)  
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)  
    com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:805)  
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:144)  
    com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:133)  
    com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)  
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:418)  
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)  
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)  
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)  
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)  
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
```

Followed by tree of components.
I thing there's nothing duplicated in code, but dataTable create a new columns and after that it's really duplicated

I have two working similar modules, and the third doesn´t work.

Have you ever met this kind of problem?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen if the bean is session scoped instead of request scoped and you're sharing this bean among multiple views. Best is to keep the bean to which the component is been bound in the request scope.

As an alternative, you can also use [`DataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html) as value instead of binding the table to `HtmlDataTable` if the functional requirement is to get the currently selected row.

Comment: You saved me (again). I've spent whole day on it and nothing. And now it works! Thank you, BalusC

Comment: BalusC, after change the scope to request, I can't work with DataTable (save, edit, delete, add to dtb) any more. It reports null exception, because object expires after response. Can I use <t:saveState> somehow? I've tried to use ViewScope but it seems doesn't with Binding HtmlDataTable. Or there is another way to solve it? Or should I realy try to use DataModel?

Comment: Solved> @ViewScoped + implements Serializable + private transient HtmlDataTable

Comment: Oh, you're using JSF 2.0? You should have mentioned that :) You can find a CRUD example with `@ViewScoped` and `DataModel<E>` here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html

Comment: I'm newbie, JSF 2.0 was my first choice. Thanks for example, I've used it already:) And I'll try to use DataModel for the next view. But I didn't understand this: "@ViewScoped breaks when any UIComponent is bound to the bean using binding attribute". It works for me, datatable binding and viewscoped together...